# Is it possible to transfer data from grid to grid in an addon?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, sapb1

I am creating an addon for `SAP B1` in Visual Studio 2015. This addon has **2 grids** and **2 buttons**. When I click the **first button**, the data I want from `SAP B1` comes to my grid. In this grid, I can sew multiple lines.
When I click the **second button**, I want the grid rows I selected above to appear in the grid below and to be deleted from the table above.
Is it possible to do that? Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible, using a loop in combination with:

```
 myTopGrid.Rows.SelectedRows

 var myVal = myTopGrid.DataTable.GetValue("myColumn1", myTopGrid.GetDataTableRowIndex(row))    

 myBottomGrid.DataTable.SetValue("myOtherColumn1", row, myVal)
```

You will need to experiment a bit but all the pieces are there.

Good luck

Comment: Can you guide a little more?